# In JavaScript how do I reach the value of objects inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hi im writing a funciton in JavaScript

Question: Define a function viewCart which does not accept any arguments. This function should loop over every item in cart to print out "In your cart you have [item and price pairs].". If there isn't anything in your cart, the function should print out "Your shopping cart is empty.".

here is what I have

```
var cart = [];

function setCart(newCart) {
    cart = newCart;
}

function getCart() {
    return cart;
}

function addToCart(item) {
    var price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    cart.push({
        item: price
    });
    console.log(item + " has been added to your cart.");
    return cart;
}

function viewCart() {
    if (cart.length != 0) {
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = cart.length; i < l; i++) {
            var ItemPriceObj = cart[i];
            var item = Object.keys(ItemPriceObj);
            var price = ItemPriceObj['item'];
            newArray.push(` ${item} at \$${price}`)
        }
        console.log(`In your cart, you have ${newArray}.`);
    } else {
        return console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
    }
}
```

My output:

> 'In your cart, you have socks at $undefined, puppy at $undefined, iPhone at $undefined.'

Wanted Output:

> 'In your cart, you have socks at $3, puppy at $23, iPhone at $400.'

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: In your code you need to add Items to your cart before it will work

Comment: Javascript* doesn't do string interpolation.  (*ES6 does)

Answer (score 1):

From Tibrogargan's comment:

```
function viewCart() {
    if (cart.length != 0) {
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = cart.length; i < l; i++) {
            var ItemPriceObj = cart[i];
            var item = Object.keys(ItemPriceObj);
            var price = ItemPriceObj['item'];
            newArray.push("" + item + " at $" + price)
        }
        console.log("In your cart, you have " + newArray.join(","));
    } else {
        return console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
    }
}
```

Using "interpolated strings" isn't valid in Javascript, instead you must concatenate them

Comment: See the [ECMA Script Compatibility Table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for more info, specifically "template literals".  (At date of writing not supported in IE, Safari, others)

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing your cart item using the string "item", not the actual item name.  Very easy fix:

Change this line:

```
var price = ItemPriceObj['item'];
```

To this:

```
var price = ItemPriceObj[item];
```

---

Maybe want to consider changing your cart element property names (mainly for readability), but also to make some things a little easier to do, for instance:

```
function addToCart(newItem) {
    var price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    cart.push({
        item: newItem, price: price
    });
    console.log(newItem+ " has been added to your cart.");
    return cart;
}

function viewCart() {
    if (cart.length != 0) {
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = cart.length; i < l; i++) {
            newArray.push(` ${cart[i].item} at \$${cart[i].price}`)
        }
        console.log(`In your cart, you have ${newArray}.`);
    } else {
        return console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
    }
}
```

Alternative for viewCart (some may argue at a cost to readability) - but this would be even more verbose if the property names were variable

```
function viewCart() {
    if (cart.length != 0) {
        console.log(cart.reduce( (p,e,i) => `${p}${i?',':''} ${e.item} at \$${e.price}`, "In your cart, you have" ));
    } else {
        return console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
    }
}
```

---

Using language features to make the code more "simple":

```js
var cart = [];

function Item(item, price) {
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
}
    
Item.prototype.toString = function() {
    return `${this.item} at \$${this.price}`
}
    
function addToCart(item, price) {
    if (!(item instanceof Item)) {
        if (typeof price === "undefined") {
            price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        }
        item = new Item(item, price);
    }
    cart.push( item );
    console.log(item + " has been added to your cart.");
    return cart;
}
    
function viewCart() {
    if (cart.length != 0) {
        console.log(`In your cart, you have ${cart.join(", ")}`);
    } else {
        return console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
    }
}

addToCart("socks", 3.00);
addToCart("puppy", 23.00);
addToCart("iPhone", 400.0);
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", viewCart, false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could do. Updated the item Name and price retrieval.

```js
var cart = [];

function setCart(newCart) {
  cart = newCart;
}

function getCart() {
  return cart;
}

function addToCart(item) {
  var price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var obj = {};
  obj[item] = price;
  cart.push(obj);

  console.log(item + " has been added to your cart.");
  return cart;
}

function viewCart() {
  if (cart.length != 0) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = cart.length; i < l; i++) {
      var itemPriceObj = cart[i];
      var itemKeys = Object.keys(itemPriceObj);
      var item = itemKeys.filter(function(key) {
        return itemPriceObj.hasOwnProperty(key)
      });
      var price = itemPriceObj[item];
      newArray.push(`${item} at $${price}`);
    }
    console.log(`In your cart, you have ${newArray}.`);
  } else {
    return console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
  }
}

addToCart("Sock");
addToCart("Phone");
addToCart("Tab");
addToCart("Book");
addToCart("Keyboard");
viewCart();
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't using the object literal notation correctly. You probably want something like this.

Change `addToCart()` to this:

```
function addToCart(item) {
    var price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    cart.push({
        item: item,
        price: price
    });
    console.log(item + " has been added to your cart.");
    return cart;
}
```

And change `viewCart()` to this:

```
function viewCart() {
    if (cart.length != 0) {
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = cart.length; i < l; i++) {
            newArray.push(` ${cart[i].item} at \$${cart[i].price}`)
        }
        var itemPriceList = newArray.join(', '); // This will concatenate all the strings in newArray and add commas in between them
        console.log(`In your cart, you have ${itemPriceList}.`);
    } else {
        return console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
    }
}
```